# Как в ShopScript(WebAsyst) сделать условие при нахождении на определенной странице сайта (например для страницы /kontakty/)?

Tags: webasyst

Например для страницы личного кабинета такое условие -

```
{$_is_personal_area = ( $wa->globals("isMyAccount") || !empty($my_nav_selected) )}

{if $_is_personal_area}
вот тут код который выполняется только на странице личного кабинета
{/if}
```

А как сделать условие для страницы /kontakty/ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
{if strpos($wa->currentUrl(), '/kontakty/') !== false}style="width: 100%; margin-top: 0;"{/if}
```